# Node.js config files not being read on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, config

I have a Node.js app which runs fine on my local machine. When I push it to Heroku it *runs* OK and I can access it in a browser, but it doesn't seem to read any of the node-config files.

I have a `config/` directory containing:

```
development.yaml
heroku.yaml
```

On Heroku I have these ENV settings:

```
NODE_ENV: production
HOST: heroku
```

The [node-config docs](http://lorenwest.github.io/node-config/latest/) suggest it should be able to read either of those config files -- I want it to read `heroku.yaml` in this case. I've tried setting `NODE_ENV` to `development` but it doesn't read that config file either.

On my local machine I can set the same environment variables as I have on Heroku, and it works as expected. What Heroku-specific thing am I missing here? What can I do to see where this is going wrong? I'm currently stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Within minutes of posting that I found a solution.

I simplified things so that in `config/` I just had:

```
development.yaml
production.yaml
```

And had these ENV settings on Heroku:

```
NODE_ENV: production
```

ie, I removed the `HOST` setting. The app ran correctly using the `production.yaml` config file.

I'm not sure why the previous (over-complex) set-up didn't work though.